# Effect of a stuck-on RegWrite control signal in a multi-cycle datapath?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

[image]

In this multi-cycle datapath:

If control signal **RegWrite** singlestuck-at-1, why and how **branch, jump & sw** instructions write in REG FILE the target address?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think might happen?

Let's note that the hardware is the union of all of the capabilities needed across all of the instructions.

Thus, if a control signal is applied to an instruction that shouldn't have it, the hardware will do something erroneous, something that would only be appropriate to a different instruction.

Can you figure out what that would be?  Maybe start by looking at how the `RegWrite` control signal works in instructions where it is valid — look at the level of how the instruction fields and the datapaths are interpreted when `RegWrite` is true.  `RegWrite` is true for (most) I-Type and (most) R-Type instructions, because they update a target register (rt or rd, respectively).

Once you understand how that control signal works (how that signal causes interpretation the instruction fields and other datapaths) for an instruction that is *supposed* to have `RegWrite`, you'll also know what it would do for instruction that *shouldn't have* `RegWrite` (because asserting that control signal will always do the same thing, in terms of the instruction fields and datapaths, whether appropriate or not for some given instruction).